# Geometry nodes instances animation, then apply Physics?

Tags: physics, geometry-nodes, rigid-body-simulation, collision

I'm trying to add Physics to some Geometry Nodes instances. I have an animation in GN, where the instances moves up, then to the right, and then I would like to apply Physics to make those instances to fall to the ground.

All I've found about GN and Physics are simple examples (a plane as Passive, and 1 object colliding with it, or a GN animated plane with an object), I need the instances collide to a plane.

The plane is a plane with Geometry nodes, so I've tried to apply GN modifier (with realize instances for the static cubes), and bake the physics, but nothing happens.

I don't know if with GN we can animate geometry to be "emulate" physics, but at least by now (7 months with Blender with no other 3d knowledge) and for me seems almost impossible.

- Animated cubes with physics, active, dynamic (if I enable Animated in Physics it does nothing):

[image: Physics+Active+Dynamic]

When the cubes start going down, that's Physics and gravity (slow, btw). But then when collides, weird things happens...

Any other options, no changes...

Can be achieved? Any help would be appreciated...

And thank you...